# why is thenextweb team page including an external php file with <script> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html-head

I was looking at thenextweb's team page
and found that inside < head>, 
they are including an external php file within
the < script> tag. Is this a good practice ? 
And what might be the purpose of doing this ?

**URL:**
http://thenextweb.com/about/team/

**Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/about/php/scriptsData.php"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript files need not have the .js extension. Sometimes you need to generate JavaScript dynamically and you end up with a .php file. For example, for placing markers in a Google map with the API, I generated the JavaScript file with php (fetching the marker locations from a database) rather than using some sort of AJAX. There's nothing wrong with it.